# sending ajax request working when the script is beneath my form but fail to work when the script is external

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image: the ajax requests]

This code works if I place it just a div beneath my form, but when I place it on my external js named main.js the form does not submit the data to my API. What is it that i am missing?. The external js is referenced at the header section. quite new on javascript... Sorry but I tried copypasting the code but the editor won't allow me, it says there is an error in my formatting

Comment: By beneath mean the script and  the form are on the same file, and the form comes first followed closely by the script above

Comment: How are you including the file? Can you post an example of you linking the js file?

Comment: <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>, this is how i m linkingthe external js file. By submitting i mean when i click the submit button nothing happens. its like the event listerner for submit action is not working. But when i include the js file just after the form within the signup.html everything works well.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankerZ      I guess that explains the downvote

Answer (score 0):

We need to know how did you link your external file and what do you mean by 'not submitting', did you get any error messages?

It cloud be that your script was rendered before your #signupForm element even exists in the DOM.

Things you can try is to place your external js before the closing body tag instead of linking it inside `<head>` section.

Also, make sure your DOM is fully loaded before executing the script.

In your main.js file:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     //YOUR CODE HERE...
  });
```

Comment: I don't get any errors. Nothing happens on  clicking the form s submit button as opposed to when the same js script is internal and comes after the form ie below the signup form

Comment: Could you accept this as the answer if it works for you?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that including the external js file at the head was the problem. because I have now included it at the end of the signup.html and it works as expected. I think it has got something to do with what @Toxnyc is saying ie the DOM has not fully loaded when the submit event listener fires up.